# find and convert all href url to another url php

Tags: php

I have a html code. now I want to find all href tags and want to convert their url into another url. I am using this code

```
public function convertLinks($message,$stats_code)
{
  $click_link = site_url('click-'.$stats_code.'email');
  $content = explode("\n", $message);
  $URLs = array();
  for($i=0;count($content)>$i;$i++)
   {
     if(preg_match('/<a href=/', $content[$i]))
      {
        list($Gone,$Keep) = explode("href=\"", trim($content[$i]));
        list($Keep,$Gone) = explode("\">", $Keep);
        $message= strtr($message, array( "$Keep" => $click_link.$Keep, ));
      }
   }
  return $message;
}
```

this code is working fine but when 2 or more href links are in one line it only converts first href link and also when ancher tag also has any other tag like class or target or any other than it fails to convert links.
please give me suitable solution
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function convertLinks($message,$stats_code)
{
  $click_link = site_url('click-'.$stats_code.'email');
  $message = str_replace('<a','{smart_href_link_epro} <a',$message);
  $content = explode("{smart_href_link_epro}", $message);
  $a_count = count($content);

  for($i=0;$a_count>$i;$i++)
   { 
     if(preg_match('/href=/', $content[$i]))
      {
        list($Lost,$Keep) = explode("href=\"", trim($content[$i]));
        list($Keep,$Lost) = explode("\"", $Keep);
        if($Keep!='#' && $Keep!='')
        $message= strtr($message, array( "$Keep" => $click_link.base64_encode(base64_encode($Keep)), ));
      }  
   } 

  return str_replace('{smart_href_link_epro}','',$message);
}
```

It works for me perfactly..